# Multiprocessing with worker.run() does work in serie instead of parallel?

Tags: python-3.4, python-multiprocessing, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to create a program which in its essence works like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(numbers):
    print(numbers)
    time.sleep(2)
    return

if __name__ =='__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=([0,1,2,3,4],))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=([5,6,7,8],))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    while(1):
        p1.run()
        p2.run()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        print('Done!')
```

The first time the processes are called via `p#.start()`, they are executed in parallel. The second time they are called via the `p#.run()` method, they are executed in series.

How can I make sure the subsequent method calls are also performed in parallel?

Edit: It is important that the processes start together. It cannot happen that process 1 gets executed twice while process 2 only gets executed once.

Edit: I should also note that this code is running on a raspberry pi v3 model B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, a thread can only be started once. After that when you call the run method, it's just a simple function. That's why it isn't run in parallel.

Comment: So what you mean is that you can start the process once, which will run in parallel. If you want to do it in parallel again, you either need to terminate and create a new process, or put the process in a loop where it waits for new input?